# Add and remove filter on certain elements from whole body

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a div (a container for a form) and a menu. I want to blurr the background, except the container and the div upon pressing a certain button from the menu, let it be:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#" onclick="someBlurrFunction()">Contact</a></div>
```

I know I can use this to to my job:

```
body > *:not(.loginContainer):not(#navDivWrapper) {
filter: blur(3px); 
}
```

But once applied, I don't really know how to remove this filter. I was wandering how can I do this with Javascript, but I'm a noob at Javascript and I can't figure it out. I was thinking about

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

And then checking for particular elements from all the selected elements, in a loop. But I can't get to the blurr style from this either.

Answer (score 2):

> But once applied, I don't really know how to remove this filter.

You can query the same css-selector and apply `filter:none`

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( "body > *:not(.loginContainer):not(#navDivWrapper)" );
Array.from( elements ).forEach( s => s.style.filter = "none" );
```